# Is it correct that `od` can't show binary number?

Tags: coreutils, od

Is it correct that `od` can't show binary number? I can't find an argument to provided to its `-t` option for showing binary number.

I feel it is natural to expect `od` to show binary number, or do I miss something? (`xxd -b` can)

Thanks.

Comment: On non-GNU systems, the manual for `od` starts of by saying "od – octal, decimal, hex, ascii dump". No "binary" included there.

Comment: @Kusalananda, by _non-GNU_ here I think you mean BSD (where the summary changed from _octal dump_ to _octal, decimal, hex, ascii dump_ in BSD4.2  (1985)). AFAICS,  you see yet different wordings in other Unices, some of them closer to GNU's than to BSD's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the [standard `od` utility](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/od.html) can not produce dumps of data as binary numbers (as characters `0` and `1` only), and neither can the GNU coreutils implementation or the implementation of `od` found on most BSD system.

Answer (score 1):

With [`ast-open`'s `od`](https://github.com/att/ast/blob/2016-01-10-beta/src/lib/libcmd/od.c), or the builtin `od` of `ksh93` if built as part of ast-open, you can use `-t b`:

```
$ ksh -c 'echo x | command /opt/ast/bin/od -tb'
0000000 01111000 00001010
0000002
```

Comment: Thanks. Is ast-open some exotic package?

Comment: @Tim, I gave a link. That's a suite of UNIX utilities that used to be maintained by AT&T research, (formerly Bell labs, where Unix was born) and includes ksh93 (the shell bash tries to copy). That lab has since been disbanded.  ast-open is still kind-of maintained on github (as a community effort not related to the AT&T team AFAICS) , but they are now focusing on ksh93 only.